# What regex expression will extract this string?

Tags: java, regex

### Question

I have this string:

```
field1=text, CmdSet=[ CmdAV=first CmdArgAV=second CmdArgAV=third CmdArgAV=fourth ], field2=text
```

Is it possible to write a regex (one line) that will capture the below in a match group?

```
first second third fourth
```

### Background

This is a syslog event coming from a Cisco ACS device. The event is being received by a SIEM solution. This SIEM solution allows us to use regex to "extract" information from the log by using match groups. We do this by typing in a "regex" line in an input field. So, for example, if I wanted to extract the value of the `CmdAV` field, I would just do `CmdAV\=(.*?)\sCmdArgAV`, and tell it to use "match group 1" (which is the only group here anyways). However, the "information" that I want to extract in my question is spread out into a single `CmdAV` and several `CmdArgAV`.

Thinking out loud, maybe a regex can be written to match everything between `CmdAV=` and `], field=text`, and then "remove" any instance of `CmdArgAV=`.

The documentation of this SIEM solution points to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ for more information on regex, so I'm guessing it uses Java.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... It should work:

```
public class Test{
 public static void main(String []args){
     String str = "field1=text, CmdSet=[ CmdAV=first CmdArgAV=second CmdArgAV=third CmdArgAV=fourth ], field2=text";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Cmd\\w*=(\\w+)");
    Matcher m =  p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // first, second, third, fourth
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: strCmd\w*=([^ ]+) to catch the first one as well

Comment: It doesn't work. I edited my question though; apologies for not having the correct strings before. I accounted for the change though. I did `Cmd\w*AV=([^ ]+)`, but it's only capturing `first`, and not the others. `CmdArgAV=([^ ]+)` also only catches `second`. I think this is a limitation of the application, because your suggestion works here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @user278064 nope, still doesn't work. It's only catching `first`. This works on gskinner.com though. I have no idea about "APIs" and all that, but could this be because the application is using the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), or that they're not accounting for someone to do something like this (i.e. not fully utilizing the API)?

Comment: @user278064 `Cmd\\w*=(\\w+)` also doesn't work. It's not matching anything. To give you an idea, the window that I'm typing in is this: http://i.imgur.com/vODlepk.jpg. When I type a regex, it highlights it. Since all of the regexes you gave me here work on gskinner.com, I'm starting to feel that the tool I'm using needs something changed. On gskinner, if I turn off "global" (`/g`), it's only catching the first part, and acts exactly like what I'm experiencing, so the tool I'm using doesn't have "global" enabled. Does this sound like a reasonable explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `randomtext` does not include `=`, why not capture everything that starts with an `=` and ends with a space - then join the array of matches with a space to get your target string...

```
/=([^ ]+) /
```

should give you array with `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth`

To make it account for randomtext containing `=`, you could do...

```
/\bstrCmd(Arg)?=(.+?)\b/
```

...and use the second capture group

Comment: It doesn't work. I edited my question though; apologies for not having the correct strings before. I accounted for the change though, and yes, `randomtext` does include `=`. I did `\bCmd(Arg)?AV=(.+)\b`, but it captures everything after the first CmdArgAV till the end of the whole log.

Comment: sorry - should be `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)` to make the capturing un-greedy, and consume as little as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Cmd\w*AV=\K(\w+)
```

As you can see into [this example](http://regexr.com?36qk6), it worked for me.

As you can read from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html), the `\K` *keeps text out of the regex match*.

Unluckly `\K` is not supported by Java (as you said). The best I can suggest (for now) it this:

```
Cmd\w*AV=(\w+)
```

and then use some `Matcher` methods.

Comment: Afaik `\K` is not supported by java

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to say the same thing. I can't find anything related to `\K` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/.